# Entering US with ESTA only, when B1/B2 visa would be required

Tags: visas, usa, esta, b1-b2-visas

My company planned to send me to the USA on a B1/B2 visa. However, due to a lack of foresight and planning, the visa will be issued far too late for the travel date.
Now they are considering sending me with an ESTA. I am unsure whether an ESTA is sufficient for my planed tasks, but this visa stuff is all Greek to me.

What are the risks to me, personally, if my company sends me with an ESTA, but a B1/B2 visa would have been required?

Comment: ESTA is a travel authorization for you to seek admission under the visa waiver program. What's your nationality? Why was a B1/B2 visa considered? Do you intend to stay for more than 90 days?

Answer (score 21):

Obligatory correction - ESTA is just permission to get on a plane. It is the **Visa Waiver Program** (VWP) that allows you to enter the US without a visa.  People often say they are "going to the US on an ESTA" but technically they are entering under the VWP, for which having an ESTA is usually necessary. If you are researching the conditions of your entry look for the Visa Waiver Program, not ESTA.

**All activities that are permitted on a B1/B2 visa are permitted under the Visa Waiver program.** So if a B1/B2 was sufficient for your travel then the VWP will be sufficient also, with the following conditions:

- You must be a citizen of a country that is eligible for the VWP.
- Your visit must be less than 90 days
- You must not be excluded from the VWP for any other reason. This includes previous denials of US visas, or connections with or visits to excluded countries.

[For more details start at this page.](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html)

Comment: In general, it is hard to get an ESTA if you don't meet those conditions (though not completely impossible, as I believe we've heard from a few dual US/elsewhere citizens who supposedly managed it somehow, but US citizens are categorically ineligible for visas and the VWP).

Answer (score 13):

The activities allowed under the Visa Waiver Program (the program that you enter the US with when using an 'ESTA') are exactly the same as those allowed when entering under a B1/B2 visa.

The only situations where a B1/B2 visa would be required for someone that is eligible to enter under the Visa Waiver Program would be if you were wanting to stay for more than 90 days, or if your ESTA application was denied.  (There are also a few other corner cases around change-of-status once you're in the US, but these are generally not relevant).

Thus presuming you are not planning on staying more than 90 days, there is zero additional risk for you entering the US using an ESTA than using a B1/B2 visa.

Comment: Well, there is one advantage of a B1/B2 visa over entering via the VWP: If you are unsure whether the reason for your stay is covered by B1/B2 (I've had such a corner case once), the eligibility of your reason is checked *beforehand*, while you are still at home and while you can still cancel your tickets and/or apply for another visa. If you go with the VWP, you risk being sent back and having wasted hours on an intercontinental flight.